# What is cp .env.local env and how do I use it?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, ethereum

Can somebody please explain this process to me in layman's terms? I'm trying to download an Ethereum application on Github and the downloaded folder comes with these instructions:

1. Clone this repo
2. cp .env.local .env
3. npm install
4. npm start

I try using the cp .env.local .env command when in the main directory but I get this:

cp : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Ryan\bundles-frontend-master.env.local' because it does not exist.

Same if I try it inside of the src folder. I am running the commands in powershell. I don't know enough about this stuff to know if I'm even trying to run the command properly? I've tried searching it but I don't have enough context to even find the solution.

If anyone would also be kind enough to provide a beginner's resource to delving into...whatever all this is that would be phenomenal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `cp .\.env.local .\.env` maybe?

Comment: @Li357 That didn't work either...am I supposed to be running the command in the same folder as the .env.example file? Because that's where I'm running it

Comment: In your project directory is their files named `.env.local` and `.env`?

Comment: @shamsNahid There is a .env.example and .env both of which are blank. No .env.local

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 01:**

In your project directory, check there is a file named `.env.local`.

Now check, if there is also a file named `.env`.

If there is a file named `.env` then, simply copy the content from `.env.local` and paste it in `.env` file.

Otherwise, if there is no such file named `.env` then first create a file named `.env`. Then copy the content from `.env.local` and paste it in `.env` file.

Now you can skip the command `cp .env.local .env`.

**Solution 2:**

Enter to the project root directory using your terminal.

Check if `.env` the file exists or not.

If the file does not exist then create a file named `.env`.

Now execute the command `cp .env.local .env`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is no .env.local file anywhere...just the .env.example which is blank. Does this mean I can't run the application?

Comment: is it possible to share the repository link?

Comment: or can you share the content of the `.env.example` file?